# why does this "hello world" golang http example slow down on osx

Tags: linux, macos, performance, go, benchmarking

I was benchmarking my little web application and noticed some significant slowdown when I was running apache bench against it after a couple of thousand requests.

`ab -n 20000 http://localhost:8080`

The first few thousand requests are fast, then it gets slower and slower. Dramatically slower. While the first thousand take maybe a second, requests 18000-20000 take up to 10 seconds.

So I was trying to find the slow parts and at some point didn't have anything to exclude anymore until I ended up with benchmarking a "hello world" style http server example. To my surprise, the same slowdown occurred.

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(200)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}
```

The same little example runs consistently fast on a linux box. It's not really a big thing because I don't plan to run the app on osx in production ;) But I'm curious what's causing the terrible slowdown on osx anyways

Comment: What do the [profiles](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) say?

Comment: Is there a deep reason you do not close your Request.Body? If you are leaking here in purpose: That's the reason for your slowdown :-)

Comment: @Volker Closing request.body does not seem to solve the problem. I have added `r.Body.Close()` right before `w.WriteHeader(200)`, and no different benchmark result.

Comment: @Ainar-G struggling getting pprof to output something useful. It reports 100% of the time being spent in a mutex. Will add the information as soon as I have figured out pprof with net/http (but then I probably already know the answer anyways ;))

Comment: @Volker I didn't know I had to call r.Body.Close() for incoming requests. Never seen any example / doc mentioning it. Will investigate this. Anyways, calling Close() on the request body doesn't change anything here. Still the same slowdown

Comment: @paukul @Volker there is no need to close the request body on server requests. From TFM: `For server requests the Request Body is always non-nil. but will return EOF immediately when no body is present.The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP Handler does not need to. `

Comment: @paukul how are you testing it on the client side? perhaps your client doesn't reuse or close connections, leading to some lingering connection leak or something that slows down the kernel.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer just a `ab -n 20000 http://localhost:8080`

Comment: @paukul try adding keepalive and some concurrency - `-k -c 100`

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer that "fixed" it! Interesting. So it's not a problem with golang but with apache bench? Mind: blown. If you create this as an answer I'll happily accept it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phrasing my comments as an answer of sorts:

I'm not sure what's the specific difference between Linux and OSX, but your server code is perfectly fine and not leaking anything. (I don't have an OSX machine to dig deeper at the moment).

My suspicion is that the client you're using (`ab`) doesn't reuse connections, and due to configuration and behavior differences between the two OSes, you're flooding the network stack with about-to-be closed connections or something along these lines.

Simply use KeepAlive in your ab script - `ab -k -c 100 -n 20000 http://localhost:8080` - and as noted in the comments this fixed it. It's also worth trying other tools like JMeter, siege, etc - or just writing a simple Go based client for this. Go has connection reuse in the http library by default.